# SVG linear gradient not working as css class in Firefox Angular JS app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

*see "update" below for newer info*

I have an SVG step chart, which works perfectly in all browsers except Firefox.
Here's how it looks in Safari 9.1:

[image]

In Firefox, the segment with the gradient is missing. The artwork was created with 4 circles and 3 rectangles, all gray.  Classes are assign to each item, and then js code elsewhere in the app assigns shapes classes as the app is used.

I have the gradient defined in the document as an SVG gradient, with the ID "in progress"

```
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="inprogress">
        <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#3e53a4"></stop>
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#cf0989"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
 </defs>
```

I refer to this gradient in my CSS:

```
.inprogress {
   fill: url('#inprogress');
 }
```

And lastly, it's assigned in the CSS to the rectangle in the chart:

```
<rect id="seg1" class="inprogress" x="35.8853125" y="14.6415625" width="142.743125" height="8.1309375"></rect>
```

This is done this way so that we can assign the class as the application proceeds in Javascript.

### UPDATE

With further testing, the codepen works in FF, since the css class is hard-coded there.  But in the app, AngularJS bindings are added for the classes (they set things like "complete" and "inprogress"). Here is where it fails, but I have no idea why.  When inspecting the code, the class is there.

Codepen URL: http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/NxMOMy?editors=1100

### UPDATE 2

Further tortuous experimenting has shown the issue (in FF only, and only in the Angular app) to be the SCSS referring to the gradient def as a url with a hash in the css class.  If, however, I use `fill: url('/#purpleGradient');` it works but **only in Firefox**.

Comment: where is that codepen you relate to ? or the code ? Firefox has usually no troubles to apply gradients to fill shapes

Comment: My bad, hit "done" too soon. Added code and link.

Comment: maybe it has to do with the selector ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPLOvy (class inprogress not seen in the code nor generated)

Comment: my codepen was wrong, i didn't notice my teammate replaced my class names with Angular bindings.  I revised it to be static.

Comment: Works in my FF on W10. Could this be an OS issue?

Comment: works fine too in w7 ff 44

Comment: The odd part is that, with further testing, works fine as it is, in a separate codepen.  When the AngularJS bindings are added for the classes (they set things like "complete" and "inprogress" as Angular bindings.

Comment: Is your CSS in a separate file? url(#purpleGradient) is actually short for url(this file#purpleGradient) (except on webkit which is a bug there).

Comment: well, it's an ID.  In the html file, an svg gradient is defined with the ID of `purpleGradient`.  Then the SCSS file is using `fill: url(#purpleGradient)` assigned to the class `inprogress`.  Lastly, the html file assigns that class to the SVG rect.  This works everywhere but FF.

Comment: Sounds like what you're doing is invalid then. A gradient in the SCCS file which is url(#purpleGradient) will (per specification) look for a gradient element in the SCCS file itself and it's not there, it's in the html file. You'd need to use an absolute URL to get it to work. Only webkit has this bug, IE also implements url matching per the CSS specification.

Comment: Except that it works just fine in every browser except FF.

Comment: what non-webkit UA are you testing it on?

Comment: It works in Chrome, Safari, and IE11 &12.

Comment: oh man, you saved my life !!! Thanx !